# Why does accessing members of class from outside gives accurate results while accessing it from member function does not work correctly?

Tags: c++, file, class, object, pointers

The below code saves data in a file using the member function **save()** and reads data back using the static function **load()**.

Loading data using **load()** function is successfull but using **dump()** function to print the result gives unexpected result, link for the image is provided for reference(https://i.stack.imgur.com/67qgH.jpg).

Accessing the members of class from **main()** gives right result.

Could anyone please find out what is wrong in my code.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    class Person {
       public:
          int ID;
          char name[20];
          Person() { ID = -1; memset(name, '\0', 20); }
          void get_data();
          void dump();
    
          bool save();
          static Person *load(int id);
    };
    
    void Person::get_data() {
    
       cout << "Enter ID: ";
       cin >> ID;
    
       cout << "Enter name: ";
       cin.ignore();
       cin.get(name, 20);
    }
    
    void Person::dump() {
       cout << "ID  : " << this->ID << endl;
       cout << "Name: " << this->name << endl;
    }
    
    bool Person::save() {
    
       ofstream outfile("person.dat", ios::app | ios::binary);
       if(!outfile) { return false; }
    
       outfile.write((char*)this, sizeof(Person));
       outfile.close();
    
       return true;
    }
    
    Person *Person::load(int id) {
    
       Person tmp, *p;
    
       ifstream infile("person.dat", ios::binary);
       if(!infile) { return NULL; }
    
       while(true) {
    
          infile.read((char*)&tmp, sizeof(Person));
          if( infile.eof() ) break;
    
          if(tmp.ID == id) {
             infile.close();
             p = &tmp;
             return p;
          }
       }
    
       infile.close();
       return NULL;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       
       if(argc == 1) { // if statement to save data to file
          Person p;
          p.get_data(); // get user input[enter image description here][1]
          if( p.save() ) cout << "Save successfull\n"; // save data
          else cout << "Save aborted\n";
       }
    
       else { // if statement to load data from file
          Person *p;
          int id;
          cout << "Enter person ID to search: ";
          cin >> id;
    
          p = Person::load(id); // load data
    
          if( !p ) {
             cout << "Person not found\n";
          } else {
             printf("%d, %s\n", p->ID, p->name); // gives right result
             p->dump(); // gives wrong result
          }
       }
    
       return 0;
    }
```

[1]:

Comment: You should give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is considered a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H).

Comment: `p = &tmp;`: `tmp` stops existing once `load()` return, so `p` points to invalid memory in your main. From that point on, you are in Undefined Behavior land, which means impredictable results.

Comment: Can't find a dupe, but you're returning a pointer to temporary object.  Crank up your compiler warnings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `load` function returns a pointer to an object that no longer exists once `load` returns. it is an error to try to access that object after it no longer exists, but `main` does so.

Fix the error.

Comment: Yes, you were right, it was an invalid memory access, hence the unpredicted behaviour. This was my first stackoverflow question so sorry for using bad practices in my code. Thank you for the help.